# when app send on app store."[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s|%d|", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__] ," will be ok?

Tags: ios, xcode, function

When app send on app store.

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s|%d|, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__]`,

will be ok? Do apple or Xcode will change it when app was realized on appstrore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be ok. Indeed they are preprocessor macros. So, the compiler will replace it at the compilation time with the proper values.

Answer (score 0):

it's completely no problem, you can get the string you want.